# Access formatting hexadecimal minimum four digits

Tags: ms-access, format, hex

In Microsoft Access I would like to convert decimal into hexadecimal, formatting it in a way that it is filled up with leading zeros when less than four digits.

I tried with

```
Format(Hex([decimalfieldname]);"0000")
```

`Format(Hex(137);"0000")` => Output: 0089

`Format(Hex(127874);"0000")` => Output: 1F382

but:
`Format(Hex(169);"0000")` => Output: A9

I would like to obtain 00A9

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Format` for strings, use `Right` instead, pad 4 zeroes by default and take the last 4 characters.

```
Right("0000" & Hex(169), 4)
```

Note that you have to implement a check if you want more than 4 digits, and want to return the full number in that case, using `IIF`

```
Iif(Len(Hex([decimalfieldname])) > 4, Hex([decimalfieldname]), Right("0000" & Hex([decimalfieldname]), 4))
```

Comment: Works just as I need it. Thanks.